# Problem with NDSolve and piecewise functions: Failure computing Filippov continuation

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise, discontinuity

I am trying to solve a first order differential equation using `NDSolve`. The differential equation is

```
g[x[t]] x’[t] + K1 x[t] + f[x[t]] = K2
```

with `x’[0]==0`. Function f is a continuous linear piecewise function and g is df/dx, and it is not a continuous function. It is easy to obtain the exact solution for the different regions, and it is a periodic oscillation with a period of about 1.555 (with the data below). My problem is about the numerical solution because I can’t obtain it using NDSolve. I have tried different options, even using `ListInterpolation` for the points in f and g, but the results I obtain is

```
NDSolve::smpf: Failure to project onto the discontinuity surface when computing Filippov continuation at time 2.031744647155892`.
```

The code is:

```
dataOrigIni = {a -> 100.2, b -> 0.99, x1 -> 1.99/100.2, x2 -> 1/0.99, K1 -> 13, K2 -> 2.5};
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{b x, x <= -x2}, {-(((a - b) x1 x2)/(x2 - x1)) + (b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1) x, -x2 <= x <= -x1}, {a x, -x1 <= x <= x1}, {((a - b) x1 x2)/(x2 - x1) + (b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1) x, x1 <= x <= x2}, {b x, x >= x2}}];
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{b , x <= -x2}, {(b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1), -x2 < x < -x1}, {a , -x1 <= x <= x1}, {(b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1), x1 < x < x2}, {b , x >= x2}}];
eqn0 = {g[x[t]] x'[t] + K1 x[t] + f[x[t]] == K2, x[0] == 0} /.dataOrigIni
sol0 = NDSolve[eqn0, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Any suggest?

Thank you

Images from the closed solution:
[image]

[image]

I have put together Alex' solution using NDSolve and the obtained by DSolve through theoretical considerations.
The comparison is below

[image]

They are very similar, but jumping in x[t] is not observed and the periodicity is missing because an increasing drift can be observed. My experience with Mathematica is limited, so I don't know if this is a normal behaviour.

Comment: How did you get exact solution with non exact parameters?

Comment: I mean I can exactly solve the differential equation in each region given by the piecewise function (I have closed expressions for x[t]). The solutions are exponential functions, first increasing and then decreasing, giving the periodic oscillation I have previously mentioned. Function f is an odd function (its shape is similar to a deformed "N" letter, more or less)

Comment: But all your parameters except `K1` are `Real`, not exact. Therefore, your solution is not exact, but some kind of numerical solution. Even with exact parameters this kind of solution is not differentiable in some points, and therefore it can't be solved with `NDSolve` directly. Probably we need to add `WhenEvent`  to this model.

Comment: I think the problem comes when x[t] reaches the peak of the "N" letter in the shape of f. Physical considerations force x[t] to jump to (a/b)x1, to the extern branch of "N" letter. I have incorporated your idea and I have introduced a WhenEvent condition for this, but the problem is the same at the same t.

Comment: The closed solution I have is a piecewise function: an increasing exponential, a jump, a decreasing exponential, a jump and starting again. I am confident with the closed theoretical solution I have. For the numerical solution with NDSolve I think the problem is as I mentioned before

Comment: Could you plot and show this solution?

Comment: Images added to the original question

Comment: Thank you! Can you published  expression of your solution for comparison with numerical one?

Comment: OK, but they are very simple. For the periodic solution, 
`DSolve[{a x'[t] + (a + K1) x[t] == K2, x[0] == (b/a) x2}, x[t], t]` until x[t] is x1 and jump to (a/b) x1,
`DSolve[{b x'[t] + (b + K1) x[t] == K2, x[0] == (a/b) x1}, x[t], t]` until x[t] is x2, jumping to (b/a)x2 and starting again. 
DSolve is used because it gives closed expresions.
The first one provides
(K2/b+K1)+((a/b)x1-K2/(b+K1)*Exp[-((b+K1)/b)t]`. You need to calculate the time to reach x1 y to do the same for the second one.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your solution. I have added a comparison with your solution at the original question. Thise differences are very strange for me.

Comment: My answer starts from the words "This is not solution just some remarks to the NDSolve methods". So it is not solution since numerical solution is not unique. Also your solution is not stable. We can try to solve it with artificial viscosity. Can you explain your model?

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a solution, but I wanted to refer to the first trial. Sorry.

Comment: The nonlinear characteristics f[x] comes from the driving point of a non-linear device (V=f[I]) inside a circuit with a linear resistor (K1), a linear capacitor and a voltage source (K2). I wanted to analyze its behaviour depending on current. I have the expressions that control the current through the circuit, the stable oscillation condition (which meet in this case), but I wanted to know if I could obtain a numerical solution in order to analyze more complex circuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not solution just some remarks to the `NDSolve` methods. First, we can pass all interval `{t,0,10}` with explicit Euler, but this solution not converge  to that proposed by  art with number of steps increasing

```
dataOrigIni ={a -> 100.2, b -> 0.99, x1 -> 1.99/100.2, x2 -> 1/0.99, K1 -> 13, K2 -> 2.5} ;
f[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{b x, 
     x <= -x2}, {-(((a - b) x1 x2)/(x2 - x1)) + (b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - 
          x1) x, -x2 <= x <= -x1}, {a x, -x1 <= x <= 
      x1}, {((a - b) x1 x2)/(x2 - x1) + (b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1) x, 
     x1 <= x <= x2}, {b x, x >= x2}}];
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{b, 
     x <= -x2}, {(b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1), -x2 < x < -x1}, {a, -x1 <= 
      x <= x1}, {(b x2 - a x1)/(x2 - x1), x1 < x < x2}, {b, x >= x2}}];
eqn0 = { x'[t] + K1 x[t]/g[x[t]] + f[x[t]]/g[x[t]] == K2/g[x[t]], 
    x[0] == 0} /. dataOrigIni;
sol0 = NDSolve[eqn0, x[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False, 
    "TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxSteps -> 10^6, 
  StartingStepSize -> 4.5 10^-2]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[x[t] /. sol0[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}], 
 Plot[f[x[t]] /. dataOrigIni /. sol0[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks very similar to the art's picture, but with `StartingStepSize ->5 10^-3` it looks quiet different

[image: Figure 2]

If we varying `StartingStepSize`then we get new solution for every new step size.   Therefore, there is no unique solution for this problem at `t>2.031744647155892` it why we have message and `NDSolve` stops.